# Understand HMAC authentication in case of site-to-site OpenVPN tunnel

Tags: security, openvpn

I have a very simple *OpenVPN* setup where *OpenVPN* server is started with `openvpn --ifconfig 10.10.10.1 10.10.10.2 --dev tun` and client is started with `openvpn --ifconfig 10.10.10.2 10.10.10.1 --dev tun --remote openvpnserver.example.com` command.

I am aware that in case of `--auth none`(disables HMAC authentication) or using default settings where HMAC authentication is enabled, the *OpenVPN* encapsulated traffic is not encrypted. However, what exactly does this authentication mean here? As I understand from *OpenVPN* manual by default packets are authenticated with HMAC using SHA1 algorithm. What benefit does this authentication provide? Based on the packet captures I can not see a difference between default settings and `--auth none`.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption prevents your data from being read. But someone could still modify them; they won't know exactly what changes they're making (due to the encryption), but depending on what you're running over the link, that could be quite catastrophic to the application.

Note that traffic analysis (looking at the size and timing of packets) can often give an attacker a pretty good way of targeting specific traffic to corrupt. So an attacker may well be able to target only the one corruption-vulnerable app running over the link.

Authentication prevents that. It allows OpenVPN to detect that someone has tampered with the packet and drop the packet, normally causing a retransmit.

(There is another meaning of authentication, which `--auth` does not control—when you're in TLS mode, each endpoint authenticates the other side to be sure it's talking [and thus encrypting to] the correct party. Without this, you could have a man-in-the-middle attack. In pre-shared key mode, this authentication is done out-of-band, when you distribute the shared keys)

Comment: I don't know what the `--auth` option configures. But on general principles of secure channels, your answer is misleading, and the part about TLS is wrong. In order to have a confidential secure channel that resist an adversary that can modify traffic, encryption alone isn't enough, because the legitimate endpoints can't know whether they are talking to each other, or talking to the adversary who is relaying traffic (decrypting the sender's traffic and reencrypting for the receiver). A secure channel needs some preestablished knowledge between the two sides, i.e. some form of authentication.

Comment: (cont.) In TLS, the client authenticates the server; the server can authenticate the client, but it's optional and not necessary to ensure confidentiality. It's possible to have confidentiality without authenticating traffic if there is some other form of preestablished knowledge such as a shared secret key (which isn't authentication as such but achieves enough to know that either you're talking to the right party or it doesn't matter — though attempting confidentiality without integrity is highly prone to higher-level vulnerabilities like replayed traffic).

Comment: @Gilles `--auth` doesn't configure that. It only configures authenticating the packets (to protect against tampering) once the session is set up. I mention the peer authentication you're talking about in my final paragraph; that's controlled by a bunch of options, depending on the mode you're running OpenVPN in. In static key mode, the admin configured two or four shared keys (two is one for HMAC, one for encrypt; four has each side use its own HMAC and encrypt key to send). There isn't really a session set up, peer authentication is implicit in having the preshared key. (continued)

Comment: @Gilles In TLS mode, you set up a CA, generate private keys and a CSR, then use your CA to sign that. Each side has a certificate. OpenVPN by default requires each side to prove its identity (it's possible to configure it not to, but unlike with most other uses of TLS the default and normal case is both sides present certificates). And it's definitely necessary to ensure confidentiality; it's only not with e.g., a web server because the server uses some other method (e.g., username and password) to establish who its talking to. [And you can do that with OpenVPN too, actually.] (continued)

Comment: @Gilles Anyway, in TLS mode, one side (arbitrarily, OpenVPN is typically run over UDP which doesn't have connections—though even when over TCP, it need not be the side doing the `listen`) is declared the server for TLS purposes in the config. Then the normal TLS exchange takes place (unless using `--tls-auth`, then another HMAC layer is put on *top* of TLS). That's controlled by the `--tls-server`, `--tls-client`, `--dh`, `--ca`, `--cert`, `--key` (or `--pkcs12*` options). Then, after verifying certificates (of both sides, unless `--client-cert-not-required` was passed),… (continued)

Comment: @Gilles each side can (optionally) check a CRL (`--crl-verify`) and do various checks on the other's identity (as asserted by the CA). There are a bunch of options for this too; and cover things like checking the certificate type (nsCertType) and key usage, the common name or full identity, etc.: `--tls-verify`, `--ns-cert-type`, `--remote-cert-ku`, `--remote-cert-eku`, `--verify-x509-name`. Finally, the server can require the client to present a username and password (this is normally only used when not requiring a client certificate, on e.g., large VPN providers). (continued)

Comment: @Gilles Finally, after all that is done, the established TLS session is used to create the encryption and authentication keys that will actually be used to encrypt and authenticate the packets. There are two possible ways this is done, controlled by `--key-method`. OpenVPN 1.x had one method, OpenVPN 2.x introduced (and defaults to) a new one. TLS is not used for the actual data packet encryption—it's only used for session setup. `--auth` only controls whether HMAC is done on the data packets. (finally done)